# timezone conversion problem in php

Tags: php, timezone, icalendar

```
$start = new DateTime('2011-05-06 19:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Tongatapu'));
$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$end   = clone $start;
$end->modify(sprintf('+ %d seconds', 1*60*60));

echo $start->format('Ymd\THis\Z'); //Output 20110506T063000Z
echo "<br/>";
echo $end->format('Ymd\THis\Z'); //Output 20110506T073000Z
```

Here the output should be 20110507T063000Z and 20110507T073000Z.... 
can anyone help...? i am not getting the appropriate results...

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be `20110507T073000Z`? You're only adding `1*60*60 seconds` = 1 hour. Why should both the day and hour change if all you do is add an hour?

Comment: one moment i think output will be above when i use new timezone as Asia/Kolkata... $start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

Answer (score 0):

The time zone Pacific/Tongatapu is GMT+13, so I would say that PHP is correct.

Comment: when i generate a meeting request from google calendar and keep timezone as Pacific/Tongatapu and 7:00 PM... in IST i recevie time as this 20110507T063000Z and 20110507T073000Z in my mail.. so why this difference...

Comment: Is 7:00 PM the approximate current time in IST? Current time in GMT is 20110506T061000Z